# Can we increase the accuracy of a classifier using sketches?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, bayes-optimal-classifier

I am using a sketch technique to improve the memory of a standard classifier (naive Bayes) with data streams. The sketch technique is composed of a sketch table (hash table) means the true values can be over-estimated due to collisions. For the first step (learning phase), data are stored in the sketch table. And during the test phase, i.e., to classify data, we take the information of data from the sketch table (that can be over-estimated as I said). Thereafter, when we are going to evaluate the accuracy of this classifier (retrieving the values from the hash table), we are going to use estimated counts and not true counts as the standard classifier, naive Bayes (because of collisions)
Is it normal to obtain with the newly created classifier (that combines naive Bayes with the sketch) a better accuracy than the standard one while using approximations? In which case this could happen? 
Because I am getting a better accuracy (not a big difference) but still weird... 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify, give enough details that someone familiar with the type of problem can respond.

Comment: I am trying to improve the result of bayes classifier using the sketches to keep the information of data processed (the learning phase). and during the test phase, I am retrieving information (approximations) from the sketches to classify the data. The question is, in comparison with the standard classifier (which is in our case naive Bayes), can we obtain a better accuracy (using approximations from the sketches)?

Comment: Done! I hope it is more clear now.